# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

when i run server.js I get this Error in my console GET http://localhost:8080/style.css  //
 GET http://localhost:8080/style.css

I have my catalog structure as follows:
I have my catalog structure as follows:

```
|-- public
      |-- style.css
      |-- client.js
      |-- server.js
      |-- package.json
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.render('index.html');

});



io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');

  });


  socket.on('chat-msg', function (message) {

    console.log('message' + message.text);


  });
});

server.listen(port);
```

**html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  type="text/css"/>

    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>


  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>HELLO COMMUNICATION</h1>

    <section id="chat">
      <ul id="messages"></ul>
      <form action="">
        <input id="m"/><button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
       <script src="client.js"></script>
   <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

          socket.on('message',function(message){

              console.log('le serveur dit'+message);
          })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**client.js**

```
var socket = io();

$('form').submit(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();   // On évite le recharchement de la page lors de la validation du formulaire



  var message={

    text : $('#m').val()


  }


  socket.emit('chat-msg',message); // On émet l'événement avec le message associé

  $('#m').val(''); //on vide le champ text

  if(message.text.trim().length !== 0){//gestion message vide

     socket.emit('chat-msg',message);

  }


  $('#chat input').focus();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your server.js?

if you are in the `public` directory and run `node server.js` I don't think the path will work correctly

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

As it will look for `public` directory that doesn't exist

Comment: when I run server.js i get error in console : GET http://localhost:8080/style.css 
localhost/:21 GET http://localhost:8080/client.js

Comment: Public is general file